# Field Entity Autocomplete filter the published nodes

Tags: 8, forms

I have a custom form with the following autocomplete entity element.

```php
$form['my_element'] = array(
  '#type' => 'entity_autocomplete',
  '#placeholder'=>'Search',
  '#target_type' => 'node',
  '#selection_settings' => [
    'target_bundles' => array('products'),
  ],
);
```

That form element autocompletes published and unpublished nodes, though.

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Comment: Normally unpublished nodes are filtered. But this depends on the user permissions. You probably are testing this logged in as admin.

Comment: I've tested it offline and it does not filter unpublished

Comment: I've put your form element in one of my forms, only changed the target_bundle to article, and it works, when I'm logged in in as admin I get all articles, when I'm logged out only the published ones.

Comment: Yes, but being disconnected from admin you also receive them, they appear in the dropdown

Comment: Did you change the permissions for the anonymous role?

Comment: No, but by default comes that you can not see the unpublished, even so permission is the one that should not have?

Comment: Default is that anonymous and authenticated can't see unpublished and the admin role can see them and the autocomplete field does respect these permissions.

Comment: In drupal 8 it seems that it does not respect it

Comment: Run another test logged in as a normal user (authenticated role), no unpublished nodes appear in the dropdown. If you can reproduce the bad behavior, you definitely should file a core issue.

Comment: With a normal user the same thing happens, also the unpublished drop down list

Comment: Are you *sure* your anon or authenticated users do not have the bypass node access permission? This definitely works correctly, most likely a configuration issue on your site

Comment: You could post the permission list of the exported user.role.anonymous config

Comment: Only has 3 permissions the anonymous role are:
View comments, view published articles and use the search